# How to do nested objects in final-form and Material UI (v1)?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, final-form, react-final-form

I want my final forms object on submit to look like this

```
{
  name : 'kk'
  address: {
      street: '123 abc',
      city: 'sf'
   }
}
```

How would I do it ? I am aware I can use dot syntax and do the same

```
<Field name="name" component="input"/>
<Field name="address.street" component="input"/>
<Field name="address.city" component="input"/>
```

But I want to allow free form button to add new `key: value` or remove them, similar to [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/kx8qv67nk5)

I see an example to do it for arrays I want to do similar but for objects instead of Array.

[Codebox example link from final form readme](https://codesandbox.io/s/kx8qv67nk5) . This is an array builder.

I want to make an object builder , just like the above example.

I am using Material UI V1 beta 23
[Final form](https://github.com/final-form/final-form) and [react final form](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form) latest versions

Comment: Also if someone has more than 1500 points, please add 2 new tags to this. `final-form` and `react-final-form`

Comment: I’m not too sure what the question is here?

Comment: @TaylorKing So I want to create a form, such that for the Address section user will have (+) and then they can add different key:values, So when yo look at code sandbox link above, it allows user to add it in an array , I want to do it as an object instead of array .

Comment: There is an example on react-final-form for this issue e.g. https://codesandbox.io/s/8z5jm6x80

Answer (score 0):

you could keep fields added by users in the form's state and them render them dynamically:

```
{this.state.fields.map(f => (
  <Address name={f.name} label={f.name} />
))}
```

Take a look at this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/3xq44l6985